# How to implement two method with same name and different return type?

Tags: java, interface, return

I wanted to know whether it is possible to implement code like this?

```
public interface A {
public void execute();
}

public interface B { 
    public String execute(); 
}

class C implements A, B {
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: sorry code for class B is like,public interface B {

 public String execute();
 
}

Comment: Questions can be edited by the owner.

Comment: i feel funny here..you bother to ask a question here rather than just try out few lines of code on your own machine..lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. This is not allowed, as the compiler would be unable to tell which version of `execute` you want to use.

If you want to overload methods, you need to vary the method parameters, e.g.:

```
   public void execute();

   public String execute(int someParam);
```

Answer (score 2):

No you can't.

Each method is required by the JLS to have a different signature:

> JLS 8.4 - *"It is a compile-time error for the body of a class to declare as members two methods with override-equivalent signatures (§8.4.2)."*

where 8.4.2 specifies *override-equivalent signatures as* method signatures that have the same method name and the same argument types after type erasure.